# Django Page loading error ?page=undefined

Tags: python, html, django, pagination

learning pagination and not understanding why page variable is undefined.  I can hover over each page object and tool tip shows correct page=page#, each button is numbered correctly as well.

**This is the function from the view of the app:**

```
def projects(request):
projects, search_query = searchProjects(request)

results = 4
page_number = request.GET.get('page')
if page_number == None:
    page_number = 1

paginator = Paginator(projects, results)

try:
    projects = paginator.page(page_number)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    page_number = 1
    projects = paginator.page(page_number)

context = {
    'projects': projects,
    'search_query': search_query,
    'paginator': paginator
}

return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)
```

**The html code for pagination is as follows:**

```html
<div class="pagination">
        <ul class="container">
            {% for page in paginator.page_range %}

            {% if page == paginator.number %}
            <li><a href="?page={{page}}" class="btn page-link btn--sub" >{{page}}</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="?page={{page}}" class="btn page-link">{{page}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

when a page is clicked, the page does not refresh to the correct page or show the current page highlighted, the initial content(1st page) is displayed.  When I print the values of the paginator attributes I can see the correct pages generated and objects referenced correctly.  Just not understanding why the anchor {{page}} references are not being returned to the view on a GET event.  This is what I suspect is causing the undefined page issue.

Thanks for looking!

Django Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

`get_page` returns a `Page` object not a `Paginator`, so when iterating you need to do `paginator.paginator.page_range`.

I would recommend refactoring your view to avoid confusion though

```py
def projects(request):
    projects, search_query = searchProjects(request)

    results = 4
    page_number = request.GET.get('page',1) # defaults to 1 if null

    paginator = Paginator(projects, results)
    page_object = paginator.get_page(page_num) # use get page to handle edge cases

    context = {
        'projects': projects,
        'search_query': search_query,
        'page_object': page_object # change paginator var name to avoid confusion
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)
```

See how you don't need to handle the exceptions if you use [get_handle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.get_page)

And your loop would now be

`{% for page in page_object.paginator.page_range %}`

Comment: Hello 2293980990,  Thanks for the recommendations.  I did make these changes, but I still have the same issue "?page=not defined" and I did fix the type-o on the page_num variable.

Comment: edit your question with all the changes involving paging. I tested it on a local project, and it works, so you might be missing something

Comment: I did a copy and paste.  I also added the following: print(request.GET), print(page_number).  This is what appeared:  <QueryDict: {'search_query': [''], 'page': ['undefined']}>
undefined  so I am still not understanding how the {{page}} reference is not being returned in the request.GET method.